# Android Not Showing Push Notification when using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i am new to android, here is how i am reciving and showing notification, but the thing is everytime i am sending notification from server the code comes to `onMessageReceived` but not not displaying any notification on Android Phone testing :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d("Message Notic", "========================>>>>> >>>>> >>>>> Some message came: " +remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }

    private void showNotification(String message) {

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
}
```

Here i am not able to get the data on two devices i tested :

1. OnePlus 5 - Android Version (Oreo 8.0.0)
2. Le Echo - Android Version (6.0.0)

Any issue you can address here will be great! Why i am not seeing any notification.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your manifest.xml :

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }



    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am receving the message till `onMessageReceived ` but its not showing notification on in the notification drawer.

Answer (score 0):

For Android O you must specify notification channel for your notification.
check the documentation
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageChannels